# What is the first and third quartile with a set of 8 numbers

Tags: statistics

I have a set of 8 numbers **0 0 1 2 4 7 8 10** and I'm trying to find Q1 and Q3. I use excel to verify that my answer is correct but it calculates a different set of quartiles and I don't know how it's coming up with that answer.

Since the number of points lower than the median is even, I take the median of the lower 50% (**0 0 1 2**)

$$\dfrac{(0+1)}{2} = 0.5$$

But when I run the `=QUARTILE(X:X, 1)` function on the same set in excel it returns the value of

$$0.75$$

Does anyone know of any ways that calculating the first quartile would result in 0.75? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The usual textbook definition does not specify exact numerical values for quartiles. Various textbooks and software programs use different methods to provide
exact numerical values. R statistical software uses one type of definition of quantile as default, but
allows the user to choose from among several different 'types' of quantiles. Differences among
types may be strikingly large for samples as small as yours. Proponents of each type give reasons why their favorite is 'best'.

```
x = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 10)
quantile(x)  # default type 7
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
 0.00  0.75  3.00  7.25 10.00 
quantile(x, type=1)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   0    0    2    7   10 
quantile(x, type=2)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 0.0  0.5  3.0  7.5 10.0 
quantile(x, type=3)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   0    0    2    7   10 
quantile(x, type=4)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   0    0    2    7   10 
quantile(x, type=5)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 0.0  0.5  3.0  7.5 10.0 
quantile(x, type=6)
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
 0.00  0.25  3.00  7.75 10.00 
quantile(x, type=8)
        0%        25%        50%        75%       100% 
 0.0000000  0.4166667  3.0000000  7.5833333 10.0000000 
quantile(x, type=9)
     0%     25%     50%     75%    100% 
 0.0000  0.4375  3.0000  7.5625 10.0000
```

Quote from R documentation on `quantile`:

> All [of these] sample quantiles are defined as weighted averages of consecutive order statistics. Sample quantiles of type (i) are defined by: $$Q_{i}(p) = (1 - \gamma)x_{j} + \gamma x_{j+1}$$ where (1 \le i \le 9), (\frac{j - m}{n} \le p < \frac{j - m + 1}{n}), (x_{j}) is the (j)th order statistic, (n) is the sample size, the value of (\gamma) is a function of (j = \lfloor np + m\rfloor) and (g = np + m - j), and (m) is a constant determined by the sample quantile type.